# Android MediaPlayer Streaming YouTube audio stream unexpected LOUD static

Tags: android, python, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, youtube-dl

What I'm attempting:
I'm using youtube-dl in a Python Daemon on a remote server to get a URL.
That URL is fed into an Android App into a MediaPlayer instance.

What is happening:
Occasionally and unexpectedly the Media player will BLAST static and play at normal speed, sometimes it will blast static and play at 1.5 times speed.
Here's a video of what happens. **HEADPHONE WARNING**
[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Agp5Glo1lQ8&feature=youtu.be)

Observations:
If there is static it is for the whole song (it isn't intermittent).
I've taken the URLs it provides and they play fine in a PC browser with no static.

It happens on different phones, and it is not just my particular phone.
It takes longer to start tracks that end up being staticy.
Tracks that are staticy make my progress bar (seconds minutes display) just behave strangely. I've seen it count up and down in the first couple seconds, and there is the 1.5x speed I was talking about.

MediaHTTPConnection throws alot of exceptions that I don't know how to handle.

```
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: disconnecting
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: RuntimeException: Unbalanced enter/exit
                     mConnection.disconnect();
```

Below is the portion of my Python daemon that returns the URL

```
ydl_opts = {
    'skip_download':True, # We just want to extract the info
    'format':'bestaudio',
    'forceurl':True,
    'ignoreerrors':True,
    'youtube_include_dash_manifest':False,
    'restrict_filenames':True,
    'source_address':'10.1.0.38',#we have to set this to force ipv4
    'logger': MyLogger()
}

def ytdl(self, url):
                url2 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+url
                ydl.download([url2])
```

Here's the (basically boilerplate) MediaPlayer

```
    public static Stack<Track> tracks = new Stack<>();

    private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private String mediaFile;
    private static int duration = 0;

    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private Boolean userPause = false;

    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder iBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public static final String TAG = "Player";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return iBinder;
    }

    class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        Player getService() {
            return Player.this;
        }
    }

    public static void seekTo(int msec){
        if(mediaPlayer != null){
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(msec);
        }
    }

    //The system calls this method when an activity, requests the service be started
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        boolean success = true;

        //An audio file is passed to the service through putExtra();
        if(intent.hasExtra("uri")){
            mediaFile = intent.getStringExtra("uri");
        } else {
            stopSelf();
            success = false;
        }
        //Request audio focus
        if (!requestAudioFocus()) {
            //Could not gain focus
            Log.d(TAG, "error requesting audio focus");
            stopSelf();
            success = false;
        }

        if (mediaFile != null && !mediaFile.equals("") && success) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Media File:" + mediaFile);
            success = initMediaPlayer();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //we cant destroy the player here because the back button fires this
        //maybe i can not fire super?
        super.onDestroy();
        /*if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        removeAudioFocus();*/
    }

    private boolean initMediaPlayer() {

        boolean error = false;

        //one time setup
        if(mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            //setup listeners
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }

        //Reset so that the MediaPlayer is not pointing to another data source
        mediaPlayer.reset();

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "setDataSource");
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mediaFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"setDataSource error:"+e);
            error = true;
        }

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "prepare");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "prepare error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = true;
        }
        return error;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Invoked when the media source is ready for playback.
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
        mp.start();
        duration = mp.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Invoked when playback of a media source has completed.
        removeAudioFocus();
        mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        //Invoked to communicate some info.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        //Invoked indicating buffering status of
        //a media resource being streamed over the network.
        if(percent%25==0)
            Log.d(TAG, "buffering:"+percent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Invoked indicating the completion of a seek operation.
        Log.d(TAG, "onSeekComplete() current pos : " + mp.getCurrentPosition());
        SystemClock.sleep(200);
        start();
    }

    //Handle errors
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        //Invoked when there has been an error during an asynchronous operation
        switch (what) {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                Log.e(TAG, "MEDIA ERROR NOT VALID FOR PROGRESSIVE PLAYBACK " + extra);
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                Log.e(TAG, "MEDIA ERROR SERVER DIED " + extra);
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                Log.e(TAG, "MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN " + extra);
                //NowPlaying.error = true;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, what + "," + extra);
                break;
        }
        PlayerActivity.error = true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusState) {
        //Invoked when the audio focus of the system is updated.
        switch (focusState) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                // resume playback
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()
                        && !userPause) {
                    pause(false);
                }
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and release media player
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.pause();
                removeAudioFocus();
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                // Lost focus for a short time, but we have to stop
                // playback. We don't release the media player because playback
                // is likely to resume
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.pause();
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing
                // at an attenuated level
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean requestAudioFocus() {

        int result = 0;
        if(audioManager == null) audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager != null) {
            result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "requestAudioFocus:"+result);
        return result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED;
        //Could not gain focus
    }

    private void removeAudioFocus() {
        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
    }

    boolean isPlaying() {
        if(mediaPlayer != null)
            return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
        return false;
    }

    //pause(true) == pause
    //pause(false) == play
    //this is used by the system
    void pause(Boolean state){
        //pause
        if (state) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        } else {
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                start();
            }
        }
    }

    //this is a pause toggle that is only triggered by the pause/play button
    boolean pause() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            userPause = true;
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        } else {
            userPause = false;
            start();
        }
        return !mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    void start(){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    int getCurrentPosition(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null)
            return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        return 0;
    }

    int getDuration(){
        return duration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like someone else is going to have this problem so I'm going to post my solution.

So I noticed a mime type error popped up for every track. The error still shows up now that I've fixed this problem but the loud static has stopped.
Here is the error that started the wheels turning:

```
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: getMIMEType
                     [seekToEx] offset:0/mCurrentOffset:-1
```

I noticed some of the URLs youtube-dl was giving me for the webm didn't have a mime type specified in the URL.
Here is an example:

```
...O8c2&mime=&pl=...
```

But all of the m4a streams had a mime type in the URL

```
...70F61&mime=audio%2Fmp4&itag=140&key...
```

So I think that while my solution isn't the best solution, it's the easiest. Since ALL the m4a streams had a mime specified I just limited myself to those streams.

The rub is this:
I'm pretty sure that if I just checked the URL for a specified mime field I could still play most webm files. The only ones that were failing (staticy) were URLs that did not have that field.

My solution:

Python only pulls m4a files:

```
...
'format':'bestaudio[ext=m4a]',
...
```

Android now passes hard coded headers:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "audio/mp4"); // change content type if necessary
Uri uri = Uri.parse(mediaFile);
Log.d(TAG, "getMimeType="+getMimeType(uri));//this is ALWAYS null
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri, headers);
```